# Negotiating a salary of a role with varied responsibilities

Tags: software-industry, salary, negotiation

I received an email from my ex boss at this company that I used to work part time in. He was asking if I'm interested in joining as a full time staff in a new role which have not been fully formed yet - business development analyst.

The company is growing fast and is looking to further automate/ move to the cloud (65% of the job) while managing/hiring part time staff (35% of the job).

What I'm concerned about is that these two responsibilities have very different skillset needed and require  different level of compensation. I expect a £45k/£25k split between the two main roles.

With that, what do you guys best recommend in negotiating a salary? What is the norm in these situation? Is it unjustified to ask for the salary which is my main role?

For context, I am a recent grad with ~6 months experience in developing AWS solutions to startups of smaller size.

Answer (score 1):

> What I'm concerned about is that these two responsibilities have very different skillset needed and require different level of compensation.

Then you should proceed to ask and obtain a more specific answer of what these tow responsibilities will consist of, so they are crystal clear.

Only then you can have a clear picture of what they will involve and be able to come up with a salary that makes sense.

Now, given that you were formerly employed as part time, it is logical that the *least* you could ask for as a full-time employee is proportional to that (i.e.: if you were part time for 4 hours and now 8, asking for at least twice the salary makes sense).

As a further suggestion, try to get in writing the description of what these responsibilities actually consist of so there is no room for misinterpretation or they changing the responsibilities further in the process.